# adb logcat - no output, adb shell works though

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I have a strange problem after Oreo update - 'adb logcat' stopped working.

Note that device is properly connected - I can debug, I can view logs in Android Studio, even I can start adb shell and do logcat but no direct logcat out from the adb command.

So in short,

```
# adb logcat
```

Absolutely no output. However, following works (logcat from the adb shell)

```
# adb shell
logcat
```

Any idea?

Comment: still looking for a solution!

Answer (score -2):

try these steps (even though your logcat is open)
in android studio go to

```
        View->Tool Windows->Logcat
```

see if it works

Comment: OP states that the logcat is working in Android Studio. It's manually calling `adb logcat` from the command line that isn't working